# How to use UIImage to represent user's wins and losses?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am new to iOS development and I am trying to make a game that shows the user's wins and losses on a horizontal bar like this:
[image]

Do I need to use two UIImageViews to do this?  Also, how can I make the bar adjust according to the wins and losses?  I would appreciate any help on how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: No, you don't need any images. A custom view is easy enough.

Comment: There are several ways to do it. For example you can use a custom UIView with custom drawRect:, you also can implement it using several views.

Comment: I would probably use a background `UIImageView` and add two `UILabels` on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This auto-generated code should be pretty close to what you need. Do what @rmaddy says and create a UIView subclass. You will want to expose two properties for the wins and losses. The drawRect method should call the method below passing the view's bounds in as the myFrame value. You'll have to play with the colors and fonts, but should otherwise be very close to what you want. And, like @earlgray said, it should draw itself dynamically based on the number of wins and loses, no need for images.

[image]

```
- (void)drawPerformanceBarWithWins: (CGFloat)wins losses: (CGFloat)losses myFrame: (CGRect)myFrame
{
    //// General Declarations
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //// Color Declarations
    UIColor* winColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.13 green: 0.78 blue: 0.13 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* loseColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.805 green: 0.055 blue: 0.055 alpha: 1];

    //// Variable Declarations
    NSString* winsText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (NSInteger)round(wins)];
    NSString* lossesText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (NSInteger)round(losses)];
    CGFloat endCapX = myFrame.size.width - 15;
    CGFloat redBoxWidth = (myFrame.size.width - 30) * losses / (wins + losses);
    CGRect redBox = CGRectMake(myFrame.size.width - redBoxWidth - 15, 0, redBoxWidth, myFrame.size.height);
    CGFloat endCapHeightScale = myFrame.size.height / 60.0;

    //// Background Rectangle Drawing
    UIBezierPath* backgroundRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: myFrame cornerRadius: 10];
    [winColor setFill];
    [backgroundRectanglePath fill];


    //// End Cap
    {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, endCapX, 0);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, endCapHeightScale);



        //// End Cap Bezier Drawing
        UIBezierPath* endCapBezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
        [endCapBezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        [endCapBezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(8.59, 0.65) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(4.4, 0) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(6.6, -0)];
        [endCapBezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(8.97, 0.75)];
        [endCapBezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(14.54, 6.31) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(11.56, 1.69) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(13.6, 3.73)];
        [endCapBezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(15.29, 15.29) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(15.29, 8.68) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(15.29, 10.88)];
        [endCapBezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(15.29, 44.71)];
        [endCapBezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(14.63, 53.3) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(15.29, 49.12) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(15.29, 51.32)];
        [endCapBezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(14.54, 53.69)];
        [endCapBezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(8.97, 59.25) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(13.6, 56.27) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(11.56, 58.31)];
        [endCapBezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(0, 60) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(6.6, 60) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(4.4, 60)];
        [endCapBezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        [endCapBezierPath closePath];
        [loseColor setFill];
        [endCapBezierPath fill];



        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }


    //// Variable Sized Rectangle Drawing
    UIBezierPath* variableSizedRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: redBox];
    [loseColor setFill];
    [variableSizedRectanglePath fill];


    //// Winning Label Drawing
    CGRect winningLabelRect = CGRectMake(myFrame.origin.x, myFrame.origin.y, myFrame.size.width, myFrame.size.height);
    CGRect winningLabelInset = CGRectInset(winningLabelRect, 5, 0);
    NSMutableParagraphStyle* winningLabelStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle.mutableCopy;
    winningLabelStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    NSDictionary* winningLabelFontAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 36], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: winningLabelStyle};

    CGFloat winningLabelTextHeight = [winsText boundingRectWithSize: CGSizeMake(winningLabelInset.size.width, INFINITY)  options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes: winningLabelFontAttributes context: nil].size.height;
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextClipToRect(context, winningLabelInset);
    [winsText drawInRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(winningLabelInset), CGRectGetMinY(winningLabelInset) + (CGRectGetHeight(winningLabelInset) - winningLabelTextHeight) / 2, CGRectGetWidth(winningLabelInset), winningLabelTextHeight) withAttributes: winningLabelFontAttributes];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);


    //// Losing Label Drawing
    CGRect losingLabelRect = CGRectMake(myFrame.origin.x, myFrame.origin.y, myFrame.size.width, myFrame.size.height);
    CGRect losingLabelInset = CGRectInset(losingLabelRect, 5, 0);
    NSMutableParagraphStyle* losingLabelStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle.mutableCopy;
    losingLabelStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

    NSDictionary* losingLabelFontAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 36], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: losingLabelStyle};

    CGFloat losingLabelTextHeight = [lossesText boundingRectWithSize: CGSizeMake(losingLabelInset.size.width, INFINITY)  options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes: losingLabelFontAttributes context: nil].size.height;
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextClipToRect(context, losingLabelInset);
    [lossesText drawInRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(losingLabelInset), CGRectGetMinY(losingLabelInset) + (CGRectGetHeight(losingLabelInset) - losingLabelTextHeight) / 2, CGRectGetWidth(losingLabelInset), losingLabelTextHeight) withAttributes: losingLabelFontAttributes];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot @picciano, I appreicate your help.

Comment: For the sake of transparency and educational aspect, it should be said that this is generated code (probably from PaintCode). While paint code makes it MUCH easier to create code like this, it is also a liability. Although a bit verbose, it is a valid solution. The code could be simplified, for example I have doubts about the necessity of bezier path.

Comment: Thanks, Earl. I agree, and you are correct about it being from Paint Code. It is very good in situations where coding efficiency is more important than highly optimized code. For example, this code above was created in about 10 minutes. Writing something like that from scratch, while more optimized, could take an hour or more. But that said, even just adding rounded corners as a frame attribute results in a bezier curve implementation under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class called WinLoseView.

It will consist of

1) custom view hierarchy

2) branding code (colors, rounding)

3) very simple public interface with two properties

- wins
- losses

The view hierarchy will have a

- two UIViews
- two UIlabels

The main view needs a bit of rounding, use UIview's layer property for that.

Comment: You only need one view with `drawRect:` implemented. No need for labels or subviews.

Comment: Very true. But you forgot to mention the tedious and hopelessly outdated CoreGraphics C API. I don't think it's a good idea to learn this C API when the OP has not even got through OOP and Obj-C/Swift basics.

Comment: You can do what I stated without using any Core Graphics C APIs. There are plenty of Objective-C/Swift APIs for drawing strings and rectangles.